# which method needs content-length field?

Tags: http, content-length, http-content-length

POST or PUT method need content-length in request header field.

Does another method(GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, CONNECT, TRACE, HEADER) also need content-length?

About content-length in Response, specification is described in rfc2616.

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

Althought, I couldn't find specification about request header..

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP specification has been updated from RFC2616. Refer to the following instead:

- RFC7230 - HTTP/1.1: Message Syntax and Routing
- RFC7231 - HTTP/1.1: Semantics and Content
- RFC7232 - HTTP/1.1: Conditional Requests
- RFC7233 - HTTP/1.1: Range Requests
- RFC7234 - HTTP/1.1: Caching
- RFC7235 - HTTP/1.1: Authentication

[Specifically Section 3.3.2 of RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2)

A Content-Length SHOULD be sent WHEN the request includes a payload body and a Transfer-Encoding header is not set.

So even a POST or PUT only need to send a Content-Length when there is a body to have a length, this just happens normally be the case with a POST and PUT due to the operations.

There is no problem with sending a Content-Length of 0 to indicate no body, but that is implied by not having a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding.

These are just the specs though, so your mileage may vary with different http implementations.

Comment: Thank you!
I understand that which method need content-length field.