# Content-Length header is not getting set for PATCH requests with empty/nil payload - GoLang

Tags: http, go, content-length, http-content-length

I observed that Content-Length header is not getting set for PATCH requests with empty/nil payload. Even if we manually set it by `req.Header.Set("content-length", "0")` it is not actually getting set in the out going request.
This strange behaviour (Go bug?) happens only for PATCH requests and only when the payload is empty or nil (or set to http.NoBody)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    url := "http://localhost:9999"
    method := "PATCH"

    payload := strings.NewReader("")
    client := &http.Client {
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, payload)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer my-token")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Length", "0") //this is not honoured

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

This is reproducible even in the latest go version `1.15`.
Just run the above code against a simple http server and see for yourself.

Is there any solution/workaround to send a PATCH request with Content-Length set to 0 ?

Comment: Absence of `Content-Length` is also acceptable to indicate a nil body. This is not a client bug, it's a server bug if it's not being handled properly.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005158/which-method-needs-content-length-field

Comment: @Marc Azure data lake gen2 storage API is throwing errors for this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/update

Comment: Furthermore, the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) clearly state that the header might be ignored.

Comment: Then they have a bug in their handler. Imagine that, Microsoft having a hard time reading an RFC.

Comment: I will report this to them, but It may take a long time for them to fix this. At the meantime is there any workaround you can think of ?

Comment: Sorry, I know how frustrating this can be (different RFC, similar problem). I can dig a bit more when I'm back at a computer. Maybe try looking for alternatives to the API or using PATCH?

Comment: thanks, using gorilla/http instead of net/http we can manually set the content-length header but the issue is gorilla/http does not support oauth2 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the HTTP client to include a `Content-Length` header with value 0 by setting TransferEncoding to `identity` as follows:

```golang
  url := "http://localhost:9999"
  method := "PATCH"
  
  client := &http.Client{}
  req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, http.NoBody)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  } 

  req.TransferEncoding = []string{"identity"} 
  req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer my-token")
  //  req.Header.Set("Content-Length", "0")
```

Note the following changes to your original code:

- **the important one**: `req.TransferEncoding = []string{"identity"}`
- the idiomatic way of specifying an empty body: `http.NoBody` (no impact on sending the length)
- commented out `req.Header.Set("Content-Length", "0")`, the client fills it in by itself
- also changed to panic on an error, you probably don't want to continue

The transfer encoding of `identity` is **not** written to the request, so except for the header `Content-Length = 0`, the request looks the same as before.

This is unfortunately not documented (feel free to file an issue with the Go team), but can be seen in the following code:

**The tedious details**:

[transferWriter.writeHeader](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transfer.go#L274) checks the following to write the `Content-Length` header:

```golang
    // Write Content-Length and/or Transfer-Encoding whose values are a
    // function of the sanitized field triple (Body, ContentLength,
    // TransferEncoding)
    if t.shouldSendContentLength() {
        if _, err := io.WriteString(w, "Content-Length: "); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if _, err := io.WriteString(w, strconv.FormatInt(t.ContentLength, 10)+"\r\n"); err != nil {
            return err
        }
```

In turn, [shouldCheckContentLength](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transfer.go#L250) looks at the transfer encoding in case of zero length:

```golang
    if t.ContentLength == 0 && isIdentity(t.TransferEncoding) {
        if t.Method == "GET" || t.Method == "HEAD" {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

The [isIdentity](https://golang.org/src/net/http/transfer.go#L593) verifies that `TransferEncoding` is **exactly** `[]string{"identity"}`:

```golang
func isIdentity(te []string) bool { return len(te) == 1 && te[0] == "identity" })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was analysing the code but did not see this workaround by manipulating the isIdentity() method call. Thanks again !!!